# Regex to find and replace a comma inside of fixed tags and changing numbers with notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

there is a XML-File with a comma instead of a point inside a specific tag.

So for example this Tag:
`<UPAvg>126,502</UPAvg>` 
should be `<UPAvg>126.502</UPAvg>`

or `<UPAvg>90,31</UPAvg>`
should be `<UPAvg>90.31</UPAvg>`

so only the comma in this specific tag should be turned into a point.
The numbers are changing, so I tried to only search for the comma and replace it with the point inside this tag. But I can't get it.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Find this: `,(?=\d*</UPAvg)`
Repleace with this `.`

- `,` Find **,**
- `?=` lookahead, when , is found the regex engine should check to see what is after (ahead).
- `\d` zero or more digits
- `</UPAvg` match `</UPAvg` literally

In plain english. When comma is found, check characters after and if there is digits after and the end tag `</UPAvg` . There is a match, replace with .

[Regex tutorial](http://goorep.se:1001/changelog/report/rSelect/PAGE_result.htm?alias=guest&set=&query=Book%20pages&$$TArticleBook1.ArticleBookK=7105&link=[[%22B510C1D203054C4D98B0215AAE499B5Ezoom%22,%22TArticleBook1%22,7105]]&hide=4)

Comment: It will be nice if you add some explanations, nevertheless +1